# How to redirect fake .htaccess path from 403 to 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal

On my Drupal sites if I go to fake url like: mysite.com/.htacess/nothing-here I get a 403 Forbidden (never hits Drupal). Is there a way we can redirect it to a 404 instead of 403?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to catch server 403 as custom 404 you need to use the [ErrorDocument](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive (assuming you're using Apache HTTP Server) :

> In the event of a problem or error, Apache httpd can be configured to
>   do one of four things :
>
> - output a simple hardcoded error message
> - output a customized message
> - internally redirect to a local URL-path to handle the problem/error
> - redirect to an external URL to handle the problem/error

So to let Drupal handle the document, set the following (httpd.conf) :

```
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
```

Note : Additional [environment variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#variables) are available when an error redirect is sent : these variables are generated from the headers provided to the original request by prepending `REDIRECT_` onto the original header name. This provides the error document the context of the original request (eg. `REDIRECT_URL`, `REDIRECT_STATUS`, `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING`).

Comment: I ended up adding this to my.htaccess file and pointing to my 404 page instead of index.php: `ErrorDocument 403 /node/137`